# How do I stop emacs from asking me if I want to exit a modified file without saving?

Tags: emacs

If I am closing a file that has modifications, emacs warns me about this and says I should press y or n.

Even when I press 'n', it still tells me that modified buffers exist and asks if I want to save anyway.

Is there a way I can stop this second 'modified buffers exist' message from appearing? Once I have pressed 'n', it should be clear to emacs that I do **not** want to save.

I **do** want it to ask me the first 'y or n' question, though.

Comment: Multiple answers available here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762686/prevent-emacs-from-asking-modified-buffers-exist-exit-anyway

Comment: Thanks for your help, R Perrin. I wish you had posted this as an answer so that I could have voted it up and marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning is built into [`save-buffers-kill-emacs`](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/emacs/emacs-24/annotate/111112/lisp/files.el#L6309). You can't disable it easily.

A simple way to get rid of it is to tell Emacs to save all buffers, by passing a prefix argument to the `save-buffers-kill-emacs` command (or `save-buffers-kill-terminal` which calls it): type `C-u C-x C-c` instead of `C-x C-c`. However you may not want to do that.

You can use the [advice facility](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) to modify the behavior of functions. Here, it's cumbersome because the code calls a generic function (`yes-or-no-p`) right in the middle of some logic that's hard to hack.

```
(require 'cl)
(defadvice save-buffers-kill-emacs
  (around save-buffers-kill-emacs-no-modified-yes-no activate compile))
  (let ((real-yes-or-no-p (symbol-function 'yes-or-no-p)))
    (flet ((yes-or-no-p (msg)
             (or (equal msg "Modified buffers exist; exit anyway? ")
                 (funcall real-yes-or-no-p msg)))))
    ad-do-it))
```

You may prefer to copy the definition and remove the offending call, however this is likely to require more maintenance as Emacs evolves.

---

Do you really need this? First, warning of unsaved changes is usually a good idea, which is why Emacs does it. Second, it's typical to start Emacs with your session and exit it when you log out, so exiting Emacs is something that happens rarely.

Comment: I agree that warning of unsave changes is good, and emacs is already doing this when it asks the *first* time if I want to save changes. I don't need it asking the *second* time, too.

Comment: The code snippet doesn't work. I tried the following corrections: removed a `)` bracket after `activate compile))`, changed `flet` to `cl-flet`. Still did not work.

Comment: @run_the_race I think this worked (without the stray parenthesis) in earlier versions of Emacs that didn't use lexical bindings. Lexical binding makes such monkey patching harder.

Comment: Found this works for Emacs 26.3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6764804/5506400

Comment: @run_the_race Beware that this removes quite a lot of stuff, such as prompting if there are active processes, or any package that registers a confirmation prompt at Emacs exit.